# how do I imply "tensorflow: `val_precision`" as it is not working for me

Tags: python, tensorflow, precision, metrics, monitor

I'm trying to use `val_precision` as monitor, from some reason it is not working. My net is:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(De, input_shape=[train_x.shape[1]], activation ='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(De, activation ='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(De, activation ='relu'))
model.add(Dense(De, activation ='relu'))
model.add(Dense(len(Tlist), activation='softmax'))
Optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.005)
model.compile(optimizer = Optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[Precision()])

num_epochs = 50
num_batch_size = 250
earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_precision', patience=20, verbose=0, mode='max')
mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint(diri + '/model_class_Hi75near.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_precision', verbose=0, mode='max')
reduce_lr_loss = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_precision', factor=0.5, patience=5, verbose=0, min_delta=1e-4, mode='max')
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=num_batch_size,\
                epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(val_x, val_y),\
                verbose=0, callbacks=[earlyStopping,\
                mcp_save,reduce_lr_loss],class_weight=class_Weight)
```

I'm getting this:

> WARNING: tensorflow: Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_precision` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,precision_1,val_loss,val_precision_1
> WARNING: tensorflow: Can save best model only with val_precision available, skipping.
> WARNING: tensorflow: Reduce LR on plateau conditioned on metric `val_precision` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,precision_1,val_loss,val_precision_1,lr

and its keep coming every epoch

so I tried change `val_precision` to `val_precision_1` all the rest of the net remain the same. So now that warning jump:

> WARNING: tensorflow: Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_precision_1` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,precision,val_loss,val_precision
> WARNING: tensorflow: Can save best model only with val_precision_1 available, skipping.
> WARNING :tensorflow: Reduce LR on plateau conditioned on metric `val_precision_1` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,precision,val_loss,val_precision,lr

I'm working on binary classification task, the target (y) is one dimensional vector of ones(1) and zeros (0)